# Does Changing Server time or time zone impact SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, farm, timezone

we are facing issue in deployment of WSPs on multi server farm. I analysis found that couple of servers where having different time zone. Thus, want to make them same. However not sure whether changing time zone of server computer will impact SharePoint or application.

Googled for it but didn't got any clear understanding.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There should be no impact rather you will fix the issue with SharePoint.

Time zone settings should be same across all SharePoint servers otherwise you will face timer service sync issue. I think that's what you are are seeing in your case.

Check this link,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2655727/sharepoint-all-servers-in-the-farm-should-be-in-the-same-time-zone

Answer (score 1):

Changing time zone of server computer will not impact SharePoint or application.

There are 2 types of SharePoint time zone:

Regional setting controls time zone for the site – this the default time zone that every user will inherit. This setting is controlled by the Administrator.

Personal setting is something each user has control over and the control to override Administrative default setting.

Please check below Article to see what will impact SharePoint time zone for users:

https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-time-zone/